# Show SVN-Branch in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

Is there a way to display the SVN-Branch I'm currently working on in Netbeans 8.1 somehow?

I found a Plugin for Git, but seems there is not much information out there for SVN.